# How do I determine file system type for a partition?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to figure out the file system type of an external partition, as per my crappy hosting company ().  I have run this command

```
myuser@mydomain:~$ sudo lsblk --fs /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_volume-nyc1-01
NAME FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1
```

but cannot determine the filesystem type (note that the "FSTYPE" colum is empty).  What else do I need to do to figure this out?

Comment: Did you check with GParted?

Comment: You could try `sudo file -s /dev/sda1`. Or if it is mounted, check the output of `mount | grep /dev/sda1`.

Comment: Then it is very likely that there is no filesystem.

Comment: @Thomas: I believe that's the answer here. Do you want to write one or shall I?

Comment: Since there doesn't appear to be an easily detectable file system in the partition, what do you expect to find on the partition? Depending on that there may be more steps to mount the file system or at least recover some data.

Answer (score 4):

In `terminal`, type `sudo parted -l` and it'll give you the info you need.

If `parted` doesn't give you an answer, and you believe that there was a valid file system there before, you may have to resort to a utility like `testdisk` to recover the partition. `Testdisk` is available the the Ubuntu repositories. See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step for some more information about how to use this tool.

Comment: If `sudo lsblk --fs` cannot detect the file system type, neither can `parted`. -1

Comment: Testdisk is a nice suggestion here. I converted my vote but `parted -l` still won't help. ;-P